# Vim: when cursor is on the last line of a file, make 'down arrow' or 'j' move cursor to the end of the line

Tags: vim

In many text editors, pressing `down arrow` when the cursor is on the last line will move the cursor to the end of the line. Is there a way to do this in vim (for `down arrow` or `j`)?

This is as opposed to simply pressing `$`.

Comment: Change source for vim. Compile and Build and Use maybe. Not aware of any shortcuts though.

Comment: I don't know a solution, but in case  you want it at the end of the line for insertion of new text, and by chance happen to be doing `$` followed by `a`, you can just `A` to append to the end of the line in insert mode...

Comment: @Abhi It is almost certainly possible to do without modifying Vim source Some vimscript with a new binding for `j` is an option.

Comment: Is there any reason you would like to have this? The only reason I can think of is to append to the end of the line and `A` works quite nicely for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
nnoremap <expr> j (line('.') == line('$')) ? '$' : 'j'
nnoremap <expr> <DOWN> (line('.') == line('$')) ? '$' : '<DOWN>'
```

We check to see if the current line is the last line. If it is we map `j` to `$` if it isn't we map `j` to `j`. (Same logic for `<DOWN>`)

Comment: This works great, but I changed `'$'` to `'<End>'` so that I could use the down arrow in insert mode (with `inoremap` as opposed to `nnoremap`). Thanks!